# How to check domain name availability with goDaddy API

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I have done a lot of research on goDaddy api and got some links also. Even though I have followed various processes to do this.

The basic command which I have tried is given below:

```
curl --verbose -X POST --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' --header "SOAPAction: \"http://wildwestdomains.com/webservices/Describe\"" --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><CheckAvailability xmlns="http://wildwestdomains.com/webservices/"><credential><Account>********</Account><Password>******</Password></credential><sCLTRID>'reseller.000000001'</sCLTRID><sDomainArray><string>example.biz</string><string>example.us</string></sDomainArray><sHostArray><string></string><string></string></sHostArray><sNSArray><string></string><string></string></sNSArray></CheckAvailability></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>' "https://api.ote.wildwestdomains.com/wswwdapi/wapi.asmx?WSDL"
```

After executing this command on terminal I am getting proper response by goDaddy api but this response is not as I need. Its something like error.

Answer (score 1):

The request you've sent via terminal gives me `Login credentials failed` error, so it is not possible to test this out without having the credentials. Also you haven't provided the exact error message. This is why I'll just give you some directions on what may be causing the problem and how to investigate further:

1. I saw that in your sample, the order of the fields is different from the one in the WSDL. This can be causing the error. By standard the order does matter, so by all means, conform to the WSDL.
2. Looking at the WSDL none of the fields in the requests is mandatory. I'm not sure about the sound design of this API, but this means that if you do not need them in the request, you may not put them in. The empty `<sting></string>` tags in `sHostArray` and `sNSArray` may be causing the error.

Try calling this operation directly with a SOAP message in the following format in order to make sure your data, format and credentials are correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://wildwestdomains.com/webservices/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:CheckAvailability>
      <ns1:sCLTRID>?</ns1:sCLTRID>
      <ns1:credential>
        <ns1:Account>?</ns1:Account>
        <ns1:Password>?</ns1:Password>
      </ns1:credential>
      <ns1:sDomainArray>
        <ns1:string>?</ns1:string>
      </ns1:sDomainArray>
      <ns1:sHostArray>
        <ns1:string>?</ns1:string>
      </ns1:sHostArray>
      <ns1:sNSArray>
        <ns1:string>?</ns1:string>
      </ns1:sNSArray>
    </ns1:CheckAvailability>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

You easily do it [from the online SOAP client available here](http://wsdlbrowser.com/soapclient?wsdl_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ote.wildwestdomains.com%2Fwswwdapi%2Fwapi.asmx%3FWSDL&function_name=CheckAvailability). Then when you manage to make it work, do it with CURL.

Hope this helps!